# Running .vbs through task Scheduler

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run a vbs script through Task Scheduler. The code for the vbs script is

```
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
'vbs opens a file specified by the path below
Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("FilePath\CombinePDFs.xlsm")
'either use the Workbook Open event (if macros are enabled), or Application.Run

ObjWB.Close False
ObjExcel.Quit
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

Then the Action in Task Scheduler is:

```
Program/Script: "FilePath\CombinePDFS.vbs"
```

With no added argument or "Start in." Trying to run this had caused it to run 20 minutes so far and it doesn't look like it's ever going to stop. It usually takes 1 minute to run.

I've read online that people say I need to be executing this in Cscript, but I have done no command coding and so I can't figure out where the CScript.exe file is supposed to go in the "Edit Action" box. Any clarification on where I need to put the Cscript.exe would be most helpful, or if you see another problem let me know.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 7, sorry should have put that in. I'll add now

Comment: Do you have `Run only when user is logged in` selected on the `General` page of the task properties.

Comment: No it's `Run whether user is logged on or not` because I'll need it to run when my computer is logged off at night. It's also set to run with highest privileges.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to use just the script name as the "Action" in Task Scheduler. Windows will execute it just as if you double-clicked it and it will run using the default app handler for the `vbs` extension (usually `wscript.exe`).

Since you're running an interactive process (launching Excel), you must have `Run only when user is logged in` selected on the `General` page of the task properties. Interactive processes cannot be launched without a logged-on user, even if you specify certain credentials for the task.

This is part of the new `"Session 0 Isolation"` introduced in Windows Vista. See the following article for more info:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2015/02/18/help-my-scheduled-task-does-not-run.aspx

Comment: So if I need the code to run when I'm not here, I'll have to find some other way to write the code and run it?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. We're not fans of it where I work. We just set our server up to auto-login to work around this unfortunate change (which makes thing much _less_ secure than before). But that's Microsoft sometimes.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work by using the `Run only when user is logged in` option?